# Issue with getting data from multiple Factories in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs- so have little bit of issue with understanding why my code is not working. Here is my problem:

1. I have 2 json data which I put in 2 factories- one listing animals and other fruits

   2. I have 2 controllers for each factory. All I need is to pull data from these 2 factories and load the name into 2 set of buttons  - Animals and Fruits
   3. Display images on clicking these buttons.

I am having trouble is displaying both buttons in a single page. It works only one at a time i.e. either display animals or fruits- but not both. 
Can anybody help me with this issue? This is my [plnkr of the app.](http://plnkr.co/edit/DF4PwlpGZYO3E2wmjTZN?p=info)

> P.S. Plunker has issue once a while with error message: Unable to
>   connect to any application instances. But app worked in plkr as well as locally

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
   <script src="animalservices.js"></script>
   <script src="fruitservices.js"></script>
   <script src="animalController.js"></script>
   <script src="fruitController.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body>

   <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Animals and Fruits</h1>
      <div class="vertical-container" class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">


               <div ng-controller="animalController">
                  <div class="col-sm-7" id="img_container"><img src="{{thisanimalData.image || 'https://clcrlsconference.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/welcome.jpg'}}" id="animalImage" class="img-responsive" width="500" >


                  </div>

                  <div class="col-sm-5">

                     <h3>Animals</h3>
                     <button id="animalbutton" class="btn btn-link vleft" ng-repeat="checkanimal in animalData" data="{{checkanimal.name}}" ng-click="clickEvent($event)">{{checkanimal.name}}</button>

                  </div>
                              </div>
               <div  class="col-sm-7"ng-controller="fruitController">
                  <button id="fruitbutton" class="btn btn-link vleft" ng-repeat="checkfruit in fruitData" data="{{checkfruit.fruit}}" ng-click="clickEvent($event)">{{checkfruit.fruit}}</button>


               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Plunker's become a joke these days, it's always down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{checkfruit.fruit}}  should be {{checkfruit.name}}

fruit is not a property on an object inside the fruitData array.

Comment: Oh no- that was an oversight. Thanks!!! I didn't change the fruit to name after I played with data fields. Another question: What strategy should I use to display image on the image container in the event of "fruit button" click? Right now, image container is inside animalController and fruitbutton is in fruitController. Any thoughts on this implementation?

Comment: Thanks, but I am little confused- can you show the example code for that data binding. I assume that I can put the img-container outside any controllers and then bind it?

Comment: I removed the comment from last night.  It was really not clear.

Comment: Here is a new plnkr with the example working.  What I did was I gave the image its own controller and service (Not necessary but easier to understand).  Then I injected the imageService into the animal and fruit controller.  then in the clickEvent functions, I set the imageSrc property on the imageService to the proper url.  http://plnkr.co/edit/qZRoTbshLflO5GaWHYfW?p=preview

Comment: David: I removed the followup question as I figured it out. Thanks for your support

Comment: Ann: Excellent.  Thanks for letting me know!  I was wondering where it went.

Comment: David: How can I do a slidein animation for images? Since I am delivering images thru' controllers, should I use $watch to introduce image transition animations? I am confused ~~~